# How to echo 5 Different Arrays?

Tags: php

I need to collect all the lines with the numbers, And turn them into str and then echo each one separately,

How can i do it please?

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'id=4321',
    1 => '4321',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 'id=7777',
    1 => '7777',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 => 'id=0101',
    1 => '0101',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    0 => 'id=1213',
    1 => '1213',
  ),
)
```

Example:

```
4321
7777
0101...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
echo $you_array[0][1]."<br>";
echo $you_array[1][1]."<br>";
echo $you_array[2][1]."<br>";
.....................
```

You can also use nl2br(), google it or stackoverflow it.

-Edit:
or  better:

```
foreach ($your_array as $subarr) {
   echo $subarr[1]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Works, Thank you!:)